# C# SqlCommand ExecuteReader not returning rows from CATCH

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, try-catch

I am trying to get the error code and message from an INSERT query when it conflicts with a PRIMARY or FOREIGN key constraint, but when the statement in the CATCH clause is executed,
SqlDataReader doesn't pick up the returned row.

Here is how I create the SqlCommand:

```
connection.Open();
string query =
    @"BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO Table1 (primkey, forkey) OUTPUT -1 AS err, NULL as msg VALUES (@primkey, @forkey)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS err, ERROR_MESSAGE() as msg
    END CATCH;";
SqlCommand command = new(query, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@primkey", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters.Add("@forkey", SqlDbType.Int);
```

And here I am executing the query in a loop to insert multiple rows:

```
command.Parameters[0].Value = primKey;
command.Parameters[1].Value = forKey;
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read(); //The query should always return a row OR throw an exception, so no need to check
switch (getInt32(reader, "err") ) //System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.'
{
    case -1: //NO ERROR
    case 2627: //PK CONSTRAINT ERROR, IGNORE
        break;
    case 547: //FK CONSTRAINT ERROR - forKey NOT FOUND
        throw new DatabaseExceptions.RecordNotFoundException(this, forKey);
    default:
        throw new DatabaseExceptions.DBException(this, getString(reader, "msg") );
}
reader.Close();
```

When no error occurs, the OUTPUT clause works and a row is picked up by the reader, but if an error occurs and is caught, the result of the SELECT statement in the CATCH clause is not picked up... Why? This query works as expected in SQL Server Management Studio.

I am using SQL Server 2022 and .NET 5

Comment: Why are you `SELECT`ing the error number and message and not `THROW`ing it? The query you have above will *never* report an error to the application because it *doesn't* error. In fact, why the `TRY...CATCH` at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET 5 is no longer supported. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core) for more information.

Comment: As for the problem, your `INSERT` statement is still likely to actually return a result set to the application layer, it'll just be empty; your application is consuming that empty result set. Don't reinvent the wheel here and instead have the error thrown (you don't need a `TRY...CATCH` for that) and then consume the error with exception handling.

Comment: Also you need to look into the USING statement in your c# code so you can properly close and dispose of your objects (connection, commands, readers, etc).

Comment: Yes, I see SqlException does contain the error code. Out of curiosity, if SqlDataReader only captures the first set of results, how would one capture a subsequent set?

Comment: I agree it would be best to avoid try/catch in this case and handle in the app layer. Otherwise, you need to invoke `NextResult` on the reader. See [The Curious Case of Undetected SQL Exceptions](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues here:

- You are catching and swallowing the exception, and returning an error row to the client, instead let the error feed through
- You are not actually checking if there is a row anyway. If you were, you could have checked the result of `reader.Read()`.
- This new way, you don't need a reader at all. Just execute the command and catch any exception.
- You need to dispose the objects with `using`

```cs
using var connection = new SqlConnection(YourConnString);
connection.Open();
const string query = @"
INSERT INTO Table1 (primkey, forkey)
VALUES (@primkey, @forkey);
";
using SqlCommand command = new(query, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@primkey", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250);
command.Parameters.Add("@forkey", SqlDbType.Int);

foreach (var obj in someList)
{
    command.Parameters["@primkey"].Value = obj.primKey;
    command.Parameters["@forkey"].Value = obj.forKey;
    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 2627)
    { //PK CONSTRAINT ERROR, IGNORE
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 547)
    { //FK CONSTRAINT ERROR - forKey NOT FOUND
        throw new DatabaseExceptions.RecordNotFoundException(obj, forKey);
    }
}
```